# mySQL data into Google Analytics

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a client who wants to retrospectively add data into GA from their back end mySQL database. The data will be transnational, for example when an existing customer makes a recurring payment via BACS/Bank Transfer.

Is it possible to do this, if so a) how and b) can it be automated?

I'm not sure if there is some script we can implement or whether we have to manually export the data into GA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite possible depending on what sort of data in in your database. Essentially, to upload anything to Google Analytics, you'll need some sort of key to *key* off of. E.g. transactionId, etc. Then you can use the [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) (located under the Property of the account) to upload your data.

To automate it, you can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport).

Comment: Blexy, can Data Import be used historically?

Comment: @PetrHavlík, hmm... I believe it's dependent on what you're importing. For example, if you're importing refund costs, using the transactionID as the key, then as long as the transactionID is present in GA, the refund will happen. I don't believe there is an option to specify date when importing, I think it does it at the hit-level.